# JavaScript function not giving the right output

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is a section of my view in which I want the result to show.

Can any one solve this problem?

When `this.waitlist` works, it should return the container like `div#sntq-waitlist` but it gives `object[ ]` instead.
Can anyone tell me why this is?

**JavaScript**

```
initLiveWaitList: function() {
  this.waitlist_ = $('sntq-waitlist');
  this.daily_status_ = $('sntq-daily_status');
  this.waiting_ = $('sntq-waiting');
  this.seated_ = $('sntq-seated');
  this.oneFour_ = $('sntq-one-four');
  this.fiveSix_ = $('sntq-five-six');
  this.seven_ = $('sntq-seven');

  this.running_ = true;

  this.loadWaitList_();
  this.intervalId_ = this.loadWaitList_.periodical(1200000, this);

  window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
      if (!this.running_) {
        this.loadWaitList_();
        this.intervalId_ = this.loadWaitList_.periodical(1200000, this);
      }
     }.bind(this));

    window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId_);
        this.running_ = false;
      }  .bind(this));
  },
```

**View**

```
  <div id="sntq-daily_status">
    <div class="loading"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don´t think I completely understood your question, but to me it looks like you are using jQuery to get the containers at the top of your code.
If this is the case you are probably just missing the ID selector.

Try to change the code to

```
this.waitlist_ = $('#sntq-waitlist');
this.daily_status_ = $('#sntq-daily_status');
//[...]
```

(note the "#" selector if you want to look for elements by ID, which seems to be the case in your example).

Comment: Well, did you try to change the selectors to include the hash (#) character before the id´s?